# Given the number of combinations when taken 2 at a time, what was the original number of items?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations

I have a set of 5 items:

```
{a,b,c,d,e}
```

I calculate the number of combinations as binomial coefficients "5 choose 2":

```
'a'    'b'
'a'    'c'
'a'    'd'
'a'    'e'
'b'    'c'
'b'    'd'
'b'    'e'
'c'    'd'
'c'    'e'
'd'    'e'
```

So the number of combinations is 10.

Knowing that the number of combinations is 10, and that I choose 2, how do I get the number of elements, i.e. the value 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By solving the equation: $$\binom{n}2=\frac12n(n-1)=10$$ in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Nailed it !!☺☺☺

Answer (score 1):

It's not too complicated.
**Just let the number be N**
Using Combinations and choosing 2 out of N we have

$$\frac{N(N-1)}2 = 10$$

You can get your N from here : )

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How to use MathJax on thr android app. I couldn't find any option.

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Comment: Got It. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: I've just edited your answer under Android.